# Postgres select from one to many table to single table rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```
kid
  id
  name

kid_workshop
  id
  kid_id
  workshop_name
```

workshop_name could be only: *arts, martial_arts, chess, soccer*

in order to increase performance, I want to create a materialized view that will look like this:

```
kid_id   name   arts   martial_arts   chess   soccer
  1      Dann   True   True           False   True
```

How can I do it? I am using postgres

Comment: You're asking for a pivot on the `kid_id` column.  I doubt this will be very performant.  In any case, what have you tried so far?

Comment: What does it mean pivot?

Comment: do you want a one line view, or many rows one?..

Comment: many rows - for each kid id a row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
create materialized view your_view as 
select
    k.id,
    k.name,
    max(case when kw.workshop_name = 'arts'
             then 'true' else 'false' end) arts,
    max(case when kw.workshop_name = 'martial_arts'
             then 'true' else 'false' end) martial_arts,
    max(case when kw.workshop_name = 'chess'
             then 'true' else 'false' end) chess,
    max(case when kw.workshop_name = 'soccer'
             then 'true' else 'false' end) soccer
from kid k
inner join kid_workshop kw
    on k.id = kw.kid_id
group by k.id,
         k.name
```

This query employs a trick while doing the pivot.  Specifically, it assigns the string `'true'` for a positive case and `'false'` to every negative case.  Since `'true'` is lexicographically greater than `'false'`, it should be retained using the `MAX()` function if present, otherwise false would be reported.  This is precisely the logic we want.

Comment: why do I need to group by and the max? Thanks Tim

Comment: This is just a standard pivot query question.  You have collections of records corresponding to each `kid_id`, and you want to _pivot_ those records into columns.  The way we do this is by aggregating over each `kid_id` and then creating the columns we want to store each piece of data.

Comment: I am getting an error:  function max(boolean) does not exist

Comment: @Dejell Try again using strings for true and false.

Answer (score 1):

smth like:

```
create materialized view mv1 as 
select 
  k.id kidid
, name
, case when workshop_name = 'arts' then true else false end arts
, case when workshop_name = 'martial_arts' then true else false end martial_arts   
, case when workshop_name = 'chess' then true else false end chess
, case when workshop_name = 'soccer' then true else false end soccer
from kid k
join kid_workshop w on w.kid_id = k.id
```

Comment: You forgot a `GROUP BY`, but I feel we should not be answering this just yet.

Comment: why group by? OP want bool_and over those fields?.. I thought he just wanted long list

Comment: No...you need to _aggregate_ over each `kid_id` and do a pivot.  This is my feeling.

Comment: why aggregate? I just want to mark rather a kid is registered to a workshop or not

Comment: @Dejell run query above against your data set and select from created view - after seeing the result please update your post to reflect why it is bad (or other suggested queries). Apparently your post can be percepted very differently

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select
  k.id kid_id,
  k.name,
  a.id is not null as arts,
  m.id is not null as martial_arts,
  c.id is not null as chess,
  s.id is not null as soccer
from kid k 
     outer join  kid_workshop a on a.kid_id = k.id and a.workshop_name = 'arts'
     outer join  kid_workshop m on m.kid_id = k.id and m.workshop_name = 'martial arts'
     outer join  kid_workshop c on c.kid_id = k.id and c.workshop_name = 'chess'
     outer join  kid_workshop s on s.kid_id = k.id and s.workshop_name = 'soccer'
```